# How to convert UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar> to String?

Tags: string, swift

I have tried this method:

```
String.stringWithCString(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>, encoding: NSStringEncoding)
```

But unfortunately, it only work with `UnsafePointer<CChar>`. And I have no idea about how to convert `UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>` to `UnsafePointer<CChar>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`struct UnsafePointer<T>` has a constructor that takes an unsafe pointer of a different
type as an argument:

```
/// Convert from a UnsafePointer of a different type.
///
/// This is a fundamentally unsafe conversion.
init<U>(_ from: UnsafePointer<U>)
```

Therefore you can create a string from `ptr : UnsafePointer<CUnsignedChar>`
with

```
let str = String.stringWithCString(UnsafePointer(ptr), encoding: someEncoding)
```

or, in the case of UTF-8 encoding, more simply with

```
let str = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer(ptr))
```

Note that the generic type `<CChar>` is automatically inferred from the context here,
i.e. the last line is equivalent to

```
let str = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(ptr))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It work. On my case, use `UnsafePointer<CChar>(ptr)` to complete the conversion.

Comment: @kukushi: If you do the conversion inside the function call then the generic type `<CChar>` is *automatically inferred* from the context. So `let str = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer(ptr))` is the same as `let str = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(ptr))` .

Answer (score 3):

Since Swift 3.0

```
let str = String(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>(ptr))
```